# Windows Server 2008 r2/ classic ASP not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I've looked at many articles and I've done everything they suggested, but my web application written in classic ASP is still not being processed.  We've upgraded our web server from windows server 2003 R2 to windows server 2008 R2 with IIS7.5 and when I moved our web application to the new server, it only displays the HTML code, the classic ASP code does not get processed. ASP is installed as well as ISAPI extensions and filters and Request filters.  I created a new classic app pool for the application.  Even a simple page with just 


This is a test


<% response.write "Hello, World!" %>
will not run the asp code.  Can anyone please help?????

Comment: You should add the suggestions that you have followed otherwise you are going to get more of the same as responses...

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to do a couple of things to make it work.
1) Make sure you have installed and enabled Classic ASP - http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/562/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis-70-and-iis-75/
2) Consider using an Application Pool running in 32 bit, especially if your app uses COM or other 32-bit components.

Take a look at:
http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2007/05/21/tips-for-classic-asp-developers-on-iis7.aspx

and 
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/559/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-70-and-iis-75/

Comment: Thanks for responding. Classic ASP is installed, but what do you mean by enable it?  Maybe that's what I'm missing.  The Application Pool is running in 32 bit.

Comment: Go to IIS Manager and opent the ISAPI and CGI Restrictions, make sure that Active Server Pages (system32\inetsrv\asp.dll) is allowed

Comment: yes, it is.  This thing is driving me crazy.

Comment: I would recommend using Failed Request tracing to try to see if that shows more details. http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis7/

Comment: Please enable all content, and enable all status codes, use something like 100-600, and enable all providers, that should generate enough details to know more about waht is going wrong.